# Составление запроса sql

Tags: sql, postgresql

В таблице report у меня есть две колонки - zone и browser. В колонке zone перечислены области - Московская, Волгоградская и тд. В колонке browser - браузеры(всего 4 варианта - Opera, Chrome, Safari, Firefox). Помогите пожалуйста написать запрос, который выдаст информацию о том, в какой области какой браузер используется чаще всего

Comment: Получите в CTE количество для каждого браузера и отранжируйте их. Во внешнем запросе выберите записи с первым рангом. Заодно решите, что выводить, если два и более браузеров показали одинаковое и максимальное количество.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как должен выглядеть внешний запрос для записей с первым рангом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если CTE по какой-то причине запрещены, можно попытаться использовать подзапросы:

```sql
SELECT sub.zone, sub.browser, sub.cc
FROM (
  SELECT zone, browser, COUNT(*) cc
  FROM report
  GROUP BY zone, browser
) sub
WHERE cc = (
  SELECT mx
  FROM (SELECT zone, MAX(cc) mx 
    FROM (
      SELECT zone, browser, COUNT(*) cc
      FROM report
      GROUP BY zone, browser
    ) sub1
  GROUP BY zone) sub2
  WHERE sub2.zone = sub.zone
)
```

[sql fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b3f1ae/1)

Comment: Спасибо, ваше решение мне помогло!

Answer (score 1):

Запрос выводит часто используемые браузеры в областях в порядке убывания количества использований. Можно выбирать только первую запись

```
SELECT zone, browser, COUNT(*) as count
FROM "report"
GROUP BY zone, browser
ORDER BY count DESC
```

Comment: А как выбирать для каждой области только первую запись?

Answer (score 0):

```sql
WITH
cte AS (
  SELECT zone,
         browser,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY zone ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) rnk
  FROM report
  GROUP BY 1,2
  )
SELECT * 
FROM cte
WHERE rnk = 1;
```

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но мне надо решить эту задачу без использования cte

Comment: @Karlail Может, Вы ещё и не знаете, как преобразовать CTE в подзапрос? А главное - откуда столь неразумное требование?

Comment: Не знаю, потому что я еще только в начале обучения)